# How to reset allocated memory and resources in c?

Tags: c, memory-management, free

My program consists of a Menu, where you can select 1 of 2 options. 
The second is just to exit the program. The first, however, is where you can find a specific sequence of bits that you choose, in a separate ".txt" file with 100.000 lines.

It does what I want the first time, and then returns to the Menu.

The problem is when the user goes for a second (or more) search. The program prints on screen random information. 
It seems like I didn't do a "reset" of the resources, memory or values on     the first search.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>    

typedef struct{

    char ID[8];
    char content[2048];
    int distance;

} DATA;

void search(){

    FILE *f;
    DADO *z=NULL;
    long int tot=0;
    int a;
    int c;
    int i;
    int j=1;
    int k=0;
    char e;
    char b[2048];

    printf("\n");

    f=fopen("DANGER_DB_LARGE.txt", "r");

    printf("\n");
    printf("How many results do you wish?\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    printf("Introduce the sequence:\n");
    scanf("%s",b);
    c=strlen(b);

    printf("\n");

    z=(DATA*)realloc(z,(++tot)*sizeof(DATA));

    while(e!=EOF){
        e=fgetc(f);

        if(k<8){
            z[tot-1].ID[k]=e;           
        }
        else if(k==8 && e=='\t'){
            continue;
        }
        else if(k>=9 && e!='\n'){
            z[tot-1].content[k-9]=e;
        }
        else if(e=='\n'){
            k=(-1);
            z=(DATA*)realloc(z,(++tot)*sizeof(DATA));
        }
        k++;
    }

    for(i=1; i<=tot; i++){
        distance(z,i,c,b);
    }

    free(z);
    fclose(f);
}
```

I proceed to store the ID and content of every single one of those 100.000 lines of text. I end the function by doing **free(z)**, but when I search again the program just prints random stuff.

Comment: `//some code that doesn't matter for this question` please post code that tells something, such as the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `e` should be an `int` as `fgetc` returns an `int`

Comment: Is it just a typo, that `DADO *z` instead of `DATA *z`?

Comment: Should `for(i=1; i<=tot; i++)` be `for(i=0; i<tot; i++)`?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi Yes sorry, it was meant to be "DATA" instead of "DADO" (I'm portuguese lol).

Comment: @WeatherVane I then increment "k", making it 0 using 'k++', at the end of that iteration of the while loop

Comment: Use of uninitialised `e` (which should be `int` by the way).

Comment: @pmg Thanks man, it worked!! Curious how that "small" tweak can make such big difference. Anyway, you really came through for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of uninitialised variables without an intervening assignment is undefined behaviour. *It may work on the first Wednesday of every month, on the first time through the loop, only when the boss is looking, ...*

```
int e; // originally was char
//...
while (e != EOF) { // uninitialised, no intervening assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

Realloc returns void by the way

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
```

plus it takes a pointer as input so its pass by reference.

**update:** This function returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory, or NULL if the request fails.

my bad.

Comment: But `z` _was_ allocated by `realloc`

Comment: realloc return void by the way void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size) @CoolGuy

Comment: you don't need to assign it to z because realloc takes pointer as input its pass by reference.

Comment: You *do* need to assign it to `z` because `realloc` takes a pointer, not a pointer to pointer.